# What is the structure of heterochromatin?

Tags: dna, chromosome, structural-biology, chromatin

A short [article](https://www.mechanobio.info/genome-regulation/what-is-chromatin-heterochromatin-and-euchromatin/) about euchromatin and heterochromatin mentions that the structure of heterochromatin usually depicted in images "has never been visualized in vivo, and its existence is questionable". Obviously, heterochromatin exists, since you can see it on photomicrographs, but what about its structure?

Is it true that the structure is not confirmed? Are there any other candidate structures?

Comment: It has never been visualized *in vivo* because the sample preparation steps involved in imaging at that level of magnification will kill the cells. Electron microscopy is very harsh; it must take place in a vacuum, and SEM involves coating the sample with ultra-thin layers of metals such as uranium.

Comment: @MattDMo - your comment sounds as an excellent answer - could you turn it into one? It's best not to answer in the comments, because it may deter others who are willing to write up a full answer from doing so.

Comment: @AliceD sure, I'll see what I can put together.